# cocos2d cannot change scene?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

Im new to cocos2d and developing in general, so this is probably a really silly mistake.
Ive searched all over and compared examples and I cant see the problem.
Ive got a simple menu with just a play button. Im trying to go to another scene when its clicked. The error is

Use of undeclared identifier 'gameScene'

but as far as I can see it is declared...

Here's my code.

```
CCMenuItemImage *play = [CCMenuItemImage
                             itemFromNormalImage:@"PlayButton.png"
                             selectedImage:@"PlayButtonPressed.png"
                             target:self
                             selector:@selector(gameScene)];

    CCMenu *selectMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:play, nil];
    //[selectMenu alignItemsVertically];
    [self addChild:selectMenu];

    -(void)gameScene:(id)sender
    {
        [[CCDirector shareDirector] replaceScene:GameScene node];
    }
```

Thanks for any help

EDIT:
Ive now got no errors, I missed the [] around GameScene node. 
BUT it keeps crashing. Heres my new code.

```
CCMenuItemImage *play = [CCMenuItemImage
                                 itemFromNormalImage:@"PlayButton.png"
                                 selectedImage:@"PlayButtonPressed.png"
                                 target:self
                                 selector:@selector(playGame)];

        CCMenu *selectMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:play, nil];
        //[selectMenu alignItemsVertically];
        selectMenu.position = ccp(160, 300);
        [self addChild:selectMenu];

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)playGame:(id)sender{
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector]replaceScene:[GameScene node]];
}
```

It doesnt seem to get to CCMenu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue. It seemed to be a problem with the selector.
I just changed it 
from:

```
CCMenuItemImage *play = [CCMenuItemImage
itemFromNormalImage:@"PlayButton.png"
selectedImage:@"PlayButtonPressed.png"
target:self
selector:@selector(playGame)];
```

to:

```
CCMenuItemImage *play = [CCMenuItemImage
itemFromNormalImage:@"PlayButton.png"
selectedImage:@"PlayButtonPressed.png"
target:self
selector:@selector(playGame:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your replace scene parameter is not correct. You have to define an actual scene that it will switch to, not just an empty node.

Comment: Thanks I had defined the scene, Id just missed a set of square brackets around GameScene node. Another problem now...

Answer (score 0):

I miss these all the time.  Watch out for that in your timers too, I've spent hours tracking down errors resulting from [self schedule:@selector(gameLogic)];  Any time you have a selector, whether its in a timer or a menu or wherever else, you need to put that in to pass data.

Additionally, if you want to make a fake menu call without a button push, maybe to force it to call in a timer or something, here's a hacky solution I've found useful:

```
id fakeButton;
[self playGame:fakeButton];
```